# get settext value from radio button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

how to get value from radio button to string, because I want to save this to my firebase as text. I will implement this radio button as drinks category with conditions. but I wanted to try first. and I think this is wrong. any suggestions? Thankyou.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton,radio1,radio2,radio3;
EditText textView;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_drinks);


    radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
    radio1=findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
    radio2=findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
    radio3=findViewById(R.id.radio_three);
    button=findViewById(R.id.btn_test);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(radio1.isChecked()) {
                textView.setText(radioButton.getText());
            }else if(radio2.isChecked()){
                textView.setText(radioButton.getText());
            }if(radio3.isChecked()){
                textView.setText(radioButton.getText());
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You're getting text on your radioButton instead of your corresponding RadioButton. Change it, you'll get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(radio1.isChecked()) {
            textView.setText(radio1.getText());
        }else if(radio2.isChecked()){
            textView.setText(radio2.getText());
        }if(radio3.isChecked()){
            textView.setText(radio3.getText());
        }
```

Edit your code

Comment: try dynamic way of doing that @MrMD

Answer (score 0):

**this is the efficient way to achieve this**

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            //no need to call each of radiobutton id 

            radiobutton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            if(selectedId==-1){

            }
            else{
                textView.setText(drinkbutton.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```